# generic.xaml not being re-packaged when modified

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2008, silverlight

What I have installed...

- Windows Vista Ultimate Service Pack 1
- Visual Studio 2008 Service Pack 1
- .Net Framework 3.5 Service Pack 1
- Silverlight 3.0

My First Problem...

I modify themes\generic.xaml and save the file and run the project and the changes I just made in themes\generic.xaml are not inside the assembly. I have used reflector to see what is in themes\generic.xaml and it is the previous version of the file.

Second Problem...

Upon realising this was happening I decided to test with modifying a C# file and I get the same problem - on compile it does not recoginise the code changes.

Note:

Before building all changes are saved via Visual Studio Option "Project and Solutions"->"Build and Run".
Using Local IIS Web Server

What I have tried...

I uninstalled ALL Silvelight, .Net Framework and Visual Studio components and re-installed only to have the problem re-occur.

Update 1:

Looks like the XAP file is not being updated. Just worked out this is only a problem when using F5 (Start Debugging) not when doing a Build Solution(Ctrl - Shift B or F7).

ANY suggestions welcome !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally worked it out and I am almost embarrassed to say what the solution is.

In Visual Studio 2008 goto Tools->Options->"Project And Solution"->"Build and run"

Turn OFF Option "Only Build Startup Projects and dependencies on run"